# Getting option is not iterable error in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, drop-down-menu, cypress

I have a drop down element with 4 options, I want to verify all of them using below code. But I am getting option is not "Iterable" error.

```
it('Verify the value of Request Type drop down', function() 
    {
        cy.get('#MailForm > div:nth-child(6) > select').find('option').then(option => {
        const actual = [...option].map(o => o.value)
        expect(actual).to.deep.eq(["Sales Request"])

      })
    })
```

If I remove the ... from

const actual = [...option].map(o => o.value) and pass const actual = [option].map(o => o.value), it giving Array [undefined] error.

can someone please suggest me.

HTML Code:

```
<select name="request_type" required="required" class="form-control"><option value="">Select Request Type</option>
<option value="Sales Lead">Sales Lead</option>
<option value="Add Insurance">Add Insurance</option>
<option value="Price Match">Price Match</option></select>
```

Comment: Please add the html code for the dropdown.

Comment: debug tip: what is the output of `console.log(option)` - clearly it isn't an object with a `.map` method (i.e. usually an Array) ... of course `[option]` is an array ... with one element, that being `option` of course, but if `option.value` is undefined, the result of the `.map` will be `[undefined]` - i.e. an array with the single value undefined

Comment: @JaromandaX seems like it's some sort of jQuery-like behaviour in that it returns some result. Similar to jQuery, it's not iterable. Yet, the documentation doesn't really seem to describe the result well - it just says it's "*the new DOM element(s) it found.*" [ref](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find). Perhaps this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as seems the intent is to check if a bunch of option values match something, rather than "how to iterate over a result from Cypress lookup".

Comment: Your error is not reproducible, probably you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: <select name="request_type" required="required" class="form-control"><option value="">Select Request Type</option>
<option value="Sales Lead">Sales Lead</option>
<option value="Add Insurance">Add Insurance</option>
<option value="Price Match">Price Match</option></select>.                                                           Above is the html code

Comment: @AlapanDas Added the HTML code. thanks.                                                                     Jaromanda X, VLAZ, thanks                                                                                              Lola Ichingbola, no I have the same error still. I am using Visual studio

Comment: Can anyone  you please guide for same, if you have an idea, I am still stuck with same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have one option "Sales Request", which is why it's not iterable.

Check the length of options

```js
cy.get('#MailForm > div:nth-child(6) > select').find('option')
  .then($options => {
    const actuals = $options.length > 1 ? [...$options].map(o => o.value)
      : [$options[0].value]

    expect(actuals).to.deep.eq(["Sales Request"])
```

Comment: "*You only have one option "Sales Request", which is why it's not iterable.*" I do not believe that to be true. Your code shows that for a single item it accesses `$options[0]` - how is it that `$options` apparently is iterable for more than one item but not iterable for a single item, yet retains indexed access? Doesn't make *any* sense from programming perspective. *At best* if it's a single item, it shouldn't even be treated as a collection and have an indexed access. It's still *bad design* but it would at least align with your explanation.

Comment: <select name="request_type" required="required" class="form-control"><option value="">Select Request Type</option>
<option value="Sales Lead">Sales Lead</option>
<option value="Add Insurance">Add Insurance</option>.     No I have the 3 options in drop down values. Above is the source code. 
<option value="Price Match">Price Match</option></select>

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the answer. but getting the same issue still. I have added the HTML code here. and drop down has the 3 values in it.